# Prove: $\mu(A)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu_n(A)$ Is a Positive Measure

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $(X,S)$ be a measurable space. Let $\mu_1,\mu_2,...$ be a sequence of positive measures on $X$ such that for all $A\in S$ the sequence $\mu_n(A)$ is monotonic increasing.

Prove/Disprove: the function $\mu:S\to \mathbb{R}$ defined $\mu(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu_n(A)$ is a positive measure

Proof:

1. Non-negativity: Let $A\in S$ for all $n$, $\mu_n(A)\geq 0$ therefore $\mu(A)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu_n(A)\geq 0$
2. Null empty set: For all $n$, $\mu_n(\emptyset)=0$ therefore $\mu(\emptyset)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu_n(\emptyset)=0$
3. Countable additivity: let $A_i \in S$, then 
   $$
   \begin{split}
   \mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right)
    &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu_n \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i \right) \\
    &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu_n(A_i) \\
    &=_{(1)} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu_n(A_i) \\
    &=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_i)
   \end{split}
   $$

I am not sure that $(1)$ is correct I know that it can be $\leq$ as it is monotonic increasing

P.S maybe because it is monotonic increasing and bounded by $\mu(A_i)$ we can write and equation?

Comment: Have a look at monotone convergence. It says that for a sequence of monotonically increasing numbers, you are allowed to interchange the sum and the limit. Now these are measures, but for each given set $A_i$, we have that $\{\mu_n(A_i)\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ is a sequence of numbers

Comment: We have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu_n(A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu_n(A_i) $$ by the monotone covergence theorem.